# Making the tableview cell into a button programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, button, cell

I've managed to add tableview cells programmatically and I've also added a search function with works!

I want the cells I made to be like buttons, you know when there is a arrow on the right side of the cell with can take you to another view.

So my question is: How do I make the cells clickable and connect them to my next view programmatically(all to the same view). Manually I can to this by click on the cell and choose Style: Basic, Accessory: Disclosure Indicator, and then connect it tho the next view controller with "push" so that I can get a navigation bar.

My code:

```
 @interface Avfall ()
 {

   NSMutableArray *totalStrings;
  NSMutableArray *filteredStrings;
  BOOL isFiltered;

 }
 @end

@implementation Avfall

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.mySearchBar.delegate=self;
self.myTableView.delegate=self;
self.myTableView.dataSource=self;

totalStrings=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"One", @"Two",@"Three", @"Four",nil];


// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this       view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
if(searchText.length==0)
{
    isFiltered=NO;
}
else
{
    isFiltered=YES;
    filteredStrings=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSString *str in totalStrings)
    {
        NSRange stringRange=[str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if(stringRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [filteredStrings addObject:str];
        }
    }
 }
 [self.myTableView reloadData];
 }


 //table view datasource and delegate methods...

 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
 return 1;
}

 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
if(isFiltered)
{
    return [filteredStrings count];
}
return[totalStrings count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    static NSString *Cellidentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier];

`if(!cell)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Cellidentifier];
}
if(!isFiltered)
{
    cell.textLabel.text=[totalStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
else //it is filtered
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [filteredStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
  [self.myTableView resignFirstResponder];
}`

Comment: you need to implement table view delegate didSelectRowAtIndexPath https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what they mean :P

Comment: you have implemented table view data source, such as numberOfRowsInSection method. Data source is similar. Try to copy the code mentioned in the link, especially listing 6-1.

Comment: I get errors from the BATTrailsViewController! What is that?

Comment: Of course you need to adjust the code accordingly. You need to change that to your view controller class. Please do some more reading and look for more examples.

Comment: Please google "uitableview examples" and read up first on how they work. If you don't understand the concepts then hacking your way is not going to help. I am assuming you didn't write this code but copied and pasted and tested it from online example?